# How to setup Angular Material for AngularJS 1.3.0

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module, angularjs-material

I am trying to implement Angular Material into an app that is using Angular 1.3.0 (the lowest version that Angular Material supports).

I have an index.php that contains the following:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

Within my app.js I have added the new ngMaterial to the modules section below..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'myControllers', 'myFilters', 'myServices', 'myDirectives',
    'ui.calendar', 'ngMaterial']);
```

When I run the app within the browser I get the following error in the console log which when clicked through is the following error on the Angular website -

```
Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Can anyone suggest why its not being loaded correctly?

Comment: how come youre still using ng1.3 and not 2.x or 4.x?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon its a old project and we cannot upgrade to 2.x or 4.x for sometime

Comment: why cant you upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

you only added `angular-material.min.css` file. need to add the `angular-material.min.js` file also. Add this script to index

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry you are right - I am now getting a Unknown provider: $$jqLiteProvider error that i'll start debugging now thanks your advice has helped a little :)

Comment: @Zabs that exception cause when the angular version and angular animate version is not compatible.Update angular version to one that equals the angular animate version

Comment: hmm ok, shouldn't how do I tell which versions aren't compatible with Angular 1.3.0?

Comment: if the versions are not equal then it's not compatible

Comment: sachila - i will dig deeper as to why this doesn't work with Angular Material even though the dependencies are all using 1.3.0 (the same version number as the AngularJS version i'm currently using) thanks again

Comment: @Zabs make sure to check as right answer if this helped :D :D